# Finding the angle made by 3 points in 3D

Tags: 3d, point, angle

As the title says, I need an algorithm that calculates the angle made by 3 points A(x,y,z) in a 3D space.

Comment: Technically with 3 points you got 3 angles that give you a total of 180°. So what angle do you want B from A,B,C points ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue Technically 3 points don't make any angle.

Comment: @ChristianRau I'm sure you understood what I meant

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue That's why I up-voted your comment. It's just that you hadn't even scratched the surface of incomplete information in this question ;)

Comment: @ChristianRau You're right, but I thought it'll be flagged a lot a faster than that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use laws of triangle.  You have the coordinates of the points, so you need to find the length of each side of the "triangle" that these points make (use the "Pythagorean theorem").  Then you can use the "law of cosigns" to find the measure of the angle.
You just gotta do a little math searching on the law of cosines and the Pythagorean theorem to figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Two vectors, and using the scalar product formula you should be able to find it. But we're not here to solve homeworks.